# signalR giving 403 when authenticated

Tags: azure, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a MVC app that uses signalR and Forms authentication and published to Azure Service - Was working fine with MVC4, SignalR 1.1.2
We upgraded to VS 2013 and the latest and greatest of all the packages, MVC 5.5.2 and signalR 2.1.2, and made the required changes for mapping SignalR via OWIN

Now when I am not logged in, signalR works as expected and connects using WebSockets. But when I do login and refresh the same page, signalR no longer works.

I get an 403 error on connecting via websockets

It then tries server sent events with comes back as (cancelled)

and then Long Polling also fails with a 403 - Forbidden error

Note that when running locally it works fine, it just when publish to azure service that I get this problem

I must be something simple I'm missing. Anybody done a similar upgrade?

Its a large app, so can't really share much code, but in essence all I'm doing is connecting to the signalR hub

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // SignalR - Initialise
            var dashboardHub = $.connection.miHub;

            // start signalR hub - this will connect the user
            $.connection.hub.start();

        });
    </script>
```

and hub class

```
public class MiHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        ConnectUser();
        return null;
    }

 ....
}
```

When I am not logged in to my app, dev tools shows the following:

```
wss://myservice.cloudapp.net/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=...         
response 101

wss://myservice.cloudapp.net/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=...
response 200
{ "Response": "started" }
```

When I logged in and hit F5 on the same page I get

```
wss://myservice.cloudapp.net/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=...
response 403
```

Comment: Don't assume that a popular package broke and no-one noticed until now. Please share your code. It's quite possible that the code you used to configure OWIN is wrong. At the very least try using Fiddler to see which URLs fail and what is the message.

Comment: Some coded added. I've use the dev tools in the browser to see that the websockets returns http status code 200 when I'm not logged in, and the same request returns 403 when I am logged in

Comment: Can you look at the response body of the failed/403'd server-sent events and long polling /connect requests? Does it contain a message like "Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection."?

Comment: The Server-sent-events returns a status of (cancelled) with no response information
The long-polling does return "Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection."

Comment: This project was built using MVC4 templates and uses WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity classes to authenticate the user. The new mcv5 templates use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin. I don't really want to re-write my login code. But is it wrong to assume MVC5 and SignalR 2 will still work with the older WebSecurity stuff?